# Printing a Java InputStream from a Process

Tags: java, printing, inputstream

`UPDATE: I found a crucial part to why this probably isn't working! I used System.setOut(out); where out is a special PrintStream to a JTextArea`

This is the code, but the issue I'm having is that the information is only printed out once I end the process.

```
public Constructor() {
    main();
}

private void main() {
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", textFieldMemory.getText(), "-jar", myJar);
                Process process = builder.start();
                InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Current output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

This is the correct output, but it is only being printed as one big block when I end the process.

Does anyone know what the issue is? If so can you help explain to me why this is happening, thank-you in advance.

Comment: The output is been buffered in the `BufferedReader`, try just reading the contents from the `InputStream` directly to see if it makes a difference

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer that the problem is probably with the buffer. However, I'd suggest just setting the `BufferedReader` buffer size to 1 with [its two parameter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader,%20int%29): `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1)`

Comment: Would using a ByteArrayOutputStream work any better? I'm completely new to streams, and this is bugging me XD

Comment: In this situation, I just use a small `byte` array and read directly from the `InputStream`.  The main reason I do this is because not all processes send newline characters as part of there output which means sometimes, you don't get any output and the process seems to never die

Comment: I doubt your buffered reader is the problem. Two quick questions: are you using `process.waitFor`? And are you reading the stream output on a separate thread?

Comment: @Perception no I'm not using `process.waitFor` and I haven't created any additional threads.

Comment: @Ciphor - you should do both. If you post a more complete sample of your code (from when you create the process to when you are done with it, including reading the output) I can provide recommendations.

Comment: @Perception added some more content.

Comment: I found a crucial part to why this probably isn't working! I used `System.setOut(out);` where out is a special `PrintStream` to a `JTextArea`

Comment: @Ciphor I would STRONGLY discourage you from redirecting output from `System.out` to a Swing component without ensuring that the output is correctly re-synced with the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer The program that starts is not mine so I cannot edit it, and the useful information it prints out is within the console. what is the best way to display this information within my application if it is not a good idea to redirect the output to my text area?

Comment: Ugh I'm way too ambitious for my knowledge as a first year, I'll sleep on this.

Comment: @Ciphor If you have control over the `PrintStream` then you need to ensure that any time it outputs to the text area, it's done within the context of the EDT.  Take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 11):

Processing the output stream of the process in a separate thread might help here. You also want to explicitly wait for the process to end before continuing with your logic:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java",
        textFieldMemory.getText(), "-jar", myJar);
final Process process = builder.start();
final Thread ioThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
ioThread.start();

process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, like I said, I think it has to do with that I redirected the console output to a JTextArea.

Comment: Yea, thats a pretty important detail. More than likely you have to explicitly flush the stream on each write then trigger a repaint of the JTextArea, in order to get the output to show up in real time.

Comment: I found something interesting if you look at my original code in the question and moved `inputStream.close();` into the while loop, I successfully get the first line printed in my `JTextArea` and then the stream is obviously closed.

Comment: Well, `close` does a `flush`, so try doing that instead and see how that affects the program.

Comment: Unfortunately InputStream doesn't have a `flush` method :/

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wrote. I meant a flush on your custom output stream, not on the input.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, from what little information there is, it sounds like your executing the process and reading the `InputStream` from within the Event Dispatching Thread.

Anything to blocks the EDT will prevent it from processing repaint requests, instead, you should use something like a `SwingWorker` which has functionality to allow you to update the UI from with the EDT.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PBDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new PBDemo();
    }

    public PBDemo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            new ProcessWorker(ta).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

    public interface Consumer {
        public void consume(String value);            
    }

    public class ProcessWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> implements Consumer {

        private JTextArea textArea;

        public ProcessWorker(JTextArea textArea) {
            this.textArea = textArea;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String value : chunks) {
                textArea.append(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // Forced delay to allow the screen to update
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            publish("Starting...\n");
            int exitCode = 0;
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe", "-jar", "HelloWorld.jar");
            pb.directory(new File("C:\\DevWork\\personal\\java\\projects\\wip\\StackOverflow\\HelloWorld\\dist"));
            pb.redirectError();
            try {
                Process pro = pb.start();
                InputConsumer ic = new InputConsumer(pro.getInputStream(), this);
                System.out.println("...Waiting");
                exitCode = pro.waitFor();

                ic.join();

                System.out.println("Process exited with " + exitCode + "\n");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("sorry" + e);
            }
            publish("Process exited with " + exitCode);
            return exitCode;
        }

        @Override
        public void consume(String value) {
            publish(value);
        }
    }

    public static class InputConsumer extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;
        private Consumer consumer;

        public InputConsumer(InputStream is, Consumer consumer) {
            this.is = is;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int in = -1;
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
//                    System.out.print((char) in);
                    consumer.consume(Character.toString((char)in));
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, like I said, I think it has to do with that I redirected the console output to a JTextArea.

Comment: There was no mention of a `JTextArea`?  Are you executing the process within in the EDT?

Comment: Sorry, yes I realise that this was the crucial part causing the issue as I commented earlier. And we haven't covered threads yet on my course sorry ><"

Comment: Code borrowed for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370583/522444) to a similar question. Many thanks!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know nothing, I "borrow" everything ;)