# Display BASH result with Java

Tags: java, swing, bash

I'm trying to run a BASH script inside a shell spawned by Java and then
display the results of said BASH script with a JTextArea.

### Here is the class where the magic is (supposed to be) happening.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Bobsors {

public static Mainframe frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame = new Mainframe();
    frame.start();

    run();

}

public static void run() {

    String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "PATH=~/Desktop/bobsors.sh"};
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        frame.setLog(process);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

### And this is the class for my frame.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Mainframe extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

public static Mainframe frame;
public static JTextArea log = new JTextArea();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public void start() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new Mainframe();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setTitle("Bobsors Java Application.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}



public void setLog(Process process) {
    log.setText(process.toString());
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Mainframe() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Shell Log", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panel.setBounds(7, 50, 434, 217);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    log.setBounds(5, 17, 424, 210);
    log.setEditable(false);
    panel.add(log);

    JLabel lblBobsors = new JLabel("Bobsors");
    lblBobsors.setBounds(12, 12, 70, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblBobsors);

    JLabel lblWorksOnLinux = new JLabel("Works on Linux only");
    lblWorksOnLinux.setBounds(12, 26, 203, 15);
    contentPane.add(lblWorksOnLinux);


}
}
```

**When running the only thing that gets displayed is this
"java.lang.UNIXProcess@509d5bae"
Does anyone know how to properly do this?**

Comment: You could having a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801069/printing-a-java-inputstream-from-a-process/15801490#15801490)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) doesn't override the default [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method inherited from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) hence why its displaying that value.

Instead you can use [`getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29), which will return an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) object which you can convert to a string like this: [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string).

Also don't forget tasks on the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) *(event dispatch thread)* must finish quickly; if they don't, unhandled events back up and the user interface becomes unresponsive, so make sure you use another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `InputStream`  and a `BufferedReader` to read output, something like this

```
 InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

Convert to String

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 String line="";
 while((line=result.readLine()) != null){
     builder.append(line + "\n");
 }
```

Please add `try` & `catch` appropriately.

Comment: And now from here on how would I properly display the builder data like a string onto the JTextArea?

Comment: You can use `builder.toString` and then `textArea.setText(stringFromBuilder)`;

Comment: To my surprise after a second run it did work.
I have no clue why it didn't work the first time but it does now!

Thank you for this answer, I will mark it as answered imideatly.

Comment: @user2875269: while lazy didn't address this, for god's sake, take care of your threading. If you try to read the BufferedReader on the Swing event thread, you'll freeze your GUI program. I suggest that you accept Mr D's answer rather than this one for this very reason.

Comment: At the moment I'm really glad that it works, however I understand why Mr. D's approach is better, I will look into it as soon as I can and if it comforts you accept his answer as the answer.

Comment: No issues man, I myself after reading his entire answer have upvoted it :)