# Run shell script from java code

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a java app that runs a bash file and inside the bash file i have a code to run another java app and it doesn't seem to work.I come from c++ where this is a very easy task but i'm not really experienced in java.
So, here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class start {

public void executeScript(){
    try{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/root/Desktop/chat/script.sh");
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Script executed..");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    start st = new start();
    System.out.println("I'm main..");
    st.executeScript();
}

}
```

Here's my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "bash started"
java Client ip_address
echo "bash finished"
```

Here's the result of this code:

> I'm main.. Script executed..

I know "Script executed.." shouldn't print because the java file i'm trying to run from the bash file is an infinite loop.

**Note:** `If i run the bash file separately in the terminal i get an infinite loop which is the intended result and this is why i know that my mistake is from this file.`

I hope I made myself clear and if not please ask for more information. Thank you.

Comment: Add some `echo` commands to the bash script so you see how far it gets.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I tried that before and the echos are not displayed in the terminal.

Comment: I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to create processes, maybe that will help.  Also, the echos should be captured in the input stream of the process (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801069/printing-a-java-inputstream-from-a-process?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa for how to print out the results)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of doing would be to use `Runtime.getRuntime()`. Something like this

```
  public void executeScript() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /root/Desktop/chat/script.sh");
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    line = "";
    while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this and now the echo statements are printed  but still i can't run the file `Client`!

Comment: @John123 I have made a minor edit which would enable you to also get the error result. I guess is, "Client" is not in the right location. Just do a "pwd" and make sure it is in the right path.

Comment: This is the output now:
`I'm main..
bash started
bash finished
Error: Could not find or load main class Client`

This is weird because as i said before if i run the client separately it works normally!

Answer (score 1):

With the above test you can not guaranty that whether it is running or not. Because clearly you told that your are running a infinite loop inside your second java application. Now my advise would be to put some `System.out.println` statement inside that infinite loop and use below java code to execute your shell script. Here in the `output.txt` file you can see the output from your shell script as well as java program and you will know whether application executed successfully or not. Also put some `echo` statement inside your shell script as well.

```
 String[] command ={"/root/Desktop/chat/script.sh", "command line param if any"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    pb.redirectOutput(new File("/tmp/output.txt"));
    String result;
    String overall="";
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((result = br.readLine()) != null){
                overall = overall + "\n" + result;
            }
            p.destroy();
            System.out.println(result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I added an `getErrorStream()` and i got this output in the file:
`I'm main.. bash started bash finished Error: Could not find or load main class Client`

Comment: Your problem is with java class path. Inside the shell script set the class path before executing the java application.

Answer (score -1):

if you start a process like you wrote `Process p = pb.start();`
it will make(we usually say fork) one more process from the java process.

1. for example, java is running as a process 'A'
2. and if the process 'A' starts another process 'B'
3. then those are running at the same time.

   (in your case, A is 'JAVA' and B is 'Shell')

so, it will be 2. and the 2 processes are running in the same time (parallely), so you will get two of those results at the same time.

Comment: But i guess this is why i used `p.waitFor() ;` because now process `A` will not start until process `B` is finished?